How to align columns across rows in flex (React Native)
How can I use React Native flex to create a table, where column are stretched to fit the widest content?
<View style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.row}>
     <View style={styles.column1}>
     <View style={styles.column2}>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.row}>
     <View style={styles.column1}>
     <View style={styles.column2}>
   </View>
</View>

How would the styles look like, so that column1 has the width of the widest element, same for column2?
I tried to apply flex: 1 and created a style per column with flex-shrink: 0 to shrink the column to its contents. I hoped applying the same style to all elements in a given column, I'd be able to size these somehow. What do I miss?
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.column1}>
          <Text>Column 1 Row 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.column2}>
          <Text>Column 2 Row 1 (long)</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.column1}>
          <Text>Column 1 Row 2 (long)</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.column2}>
          <Text>Column 2 Row 2</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  column1: {
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  column2: {
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
});

export default App;

Is my approach of using flexbox correct?
